# how to render a component over a particular element in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have my react functional component as:

```
import React from "react";
import { ReactDOM } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import Cart from "./components/cart";

function Shop() {
  const [showCart, setShowCart] = useState(false);
  const cartPreview = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.parentElement.parentElement);
    ReactDOM.render(<Cart />, e.target.parentElement.parentElement);
    setShowCart(!showCart);
  };
}
```

Below is the button for cartPreview function:

```
<div className="flex justify-center m-auto w-full">
  <button
    onClick={cartPreview}
    className="hover:bg-green-800 shadow-md bg-green-900 text-gray-100 rounded-md p-2 h-10"
  >
    Add To Cart
  </button>
</div>
```

It shows runtime error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'render')`

I want to render the cart component over the div which contain cartPreview button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Comment: whats difference between " import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom' " and " import { ReactDOM } from 'react' "

Comment: ReactDom does not exist in 'react' module but in 'react-dom' module.
import * as N is importing the module and refer it to N